Why would you not issue orders to a facility?
The Bastion rules in the DMG say (p. 336)

On a Bastion turn, a character in their Bastion can issue special orders - called Bastion orders- to one or more of their Bastion's special facilities. A character needn't issue orders to all the special facilities in their Bastion on a given Bastion turn.

The effects of the various special facilities are - as far as I can tell - entirely beneficial. They give free magic items, poisons, information, charms, additional defenders etc.
There also is the "Maintenance" order, but that one can only be given to the entire Bastion, not to individual facilities, so I assume if you issue no orders to one, they also do not do maintenance.
Why would one not issue facility orders, if one has the ability to? The only reason I can see is if a facility is maxed out, for example a Menagerie that is already fully stocked, issuing the order would not improve it further. Is there anything else I am missing?

To Be Explicitly Optional
There are other places in the new rules where you are explicitly given the option to "do nothing," for example, from the Combat Rules

Doing Nothing on Your Turn. You can forgo moving, taking an action, or doing anything at all on your turn.

Why would you want to just stand there and twiddle your thumbs in active combat? Maybe you have some RP reason...character is afraid of gnolls or something and 'freezes up.' Or maybe you're too far away from the fight and it's about to end, so you just say 'skip' so the player who is in the fight and clearly winning can wrap the combat up. Or whatever.
I suspect the same principle is in play with the Bastion rules. They explicitly state that you don't have to take Bastion Actions if you don't want to, just like they explicitly state that you don't have to take Combat Actions if you don't want to.
As for reasons you may choose not to, I'm not going to go too far on this as it's branching into opinion...but here are some examples drawn from other games I've played that have 'base management' rules (including some 5E homebrew)

I have things the way I like them, and am happy (like a full menagerie)
We run [bastion turns] between sessions, and I have too much going on IRL this week
My character is not available to manage the bastion due to RP reasons
I'm really not sure what to do, so let's just skip my turn this time so I'm not holding up the game


Your last reason is, in my opinion, really important and might be worth emphasing a bit more: Managing Bastions costs Game Time, i.e. the time of the DM and all players on the table. Sure it might be optimal to issue an order every single time, but if it takes you an hour to resolve that action or come up with what you do, anyone else at the table will just be forced to sit their and wait until the game resumes, really ruining the mood of the game night in the process.

I agree with what you say. I would expand on the "RP reason not to do anything" part. It's more than having an RP reason, imo. It's a fundamental part of the game that you, the player, is in control of your character. The game should never force you to be proactive about anything.
